# Get the ID of the direct parent page

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

I've seen plenty of tutorials on how to get the ID of the upper-most parent, but I can't seem to find anything on how to get the ID from the direct parent.

Eg;

```
- Big John
  - Little John
    - Baby John
```

How, if I'm on the Baby John page, can I get the ID of Little John and not of Big John?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that you're asking how to do it with code? (Doing it in backend is pretty easy - just try to edit parent page and see the ID in URL).

So how to check post parent in code? It's also very easy - direct parent is stored in `post_parent` property. If post has no parent, it will be `0`.

So all you have to do is:

```
global $post;
$direct_parent = $post->post_parent;
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works.  I think you should accept this as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$post->post_parent` ?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Comment: A better reference page might be [WP_Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).